# cumulative sum of a cell of function handles

Tags: matlab, function-handle

I have a cell of function handles:

```
f{1}=@(x)a1(x);
f{2}=@(x)a2(x);
...
f{N}=@(x)aN(x);
```

N is a large number here. What is the most convenient way to perform cumulative sum on all these function handles? e.g. I want to have a cell of new function g{} with:

```
g{1}=f{1};
g{2}=f{1}+f{2};
...
g{N}=f{1}+...+f{N}.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can do with a *single function* `g` that returns the cumulative sum for *scalar* `x`:

```
g = @(x) cumsum(cellfun(@(y) y(x), f))
```

Example:

```
f{1} = @(x) x;
f{2} = @(x) x^2;
f{3} = @(x) x^3;
g = @(x) cumsum(cellfun(@(y) y(x), f))
g(3)
ans =
     3    12    39
```

Explanation: `cellfun` takes each component function `f{1}`,  `f{2}` etc and returns the result of evaluating that function at `x`. The result for each function should be scalar. The cumulative sum of all those values is then computed.

Comment: It didn't give me correct answer. Could you elaborate on it? Thanks.I found a cumbersome way to work around: g=@(x)cellfun(@(f)f(x),f);gg=@(x)cumsum(g(x)).Now gg(x) gives me what I wanted. Is there any smarter way to do this though?

Comment: @Void Sorry, there was a mistake. Please see now